# Merge div with same class into bigger div with same class

Tags: php, html, regex

I am trying to merge same div class with the parent div class.
Tried here to match the regex http://www.regexr.com/3bim9. But I am not quite good at this also I don't get any on how to do this and thinking for about 4 hours. Also this should work for multiple inner divs. I have a hunch that it can be done with preg_replace

Current output:

```
<div class="dotted-highlight">
  Here is a check list to determine whether.
  <div class="dotted-highlight">
    Tick all those apply to you. The more boxes you tick.
  </div>
</div>
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
<div class="dotted-highlight">
  Here is a check list to determine whether.
  Tick all those apply to you. The more boxes you tick.
</div>
```

PHP

```
<?php

$textarea = '<div class="dotted-highlight">
      Here is a check list to determine whether.
      <div class="dotted-highlight">
        Tick all those apply to you. The more boxes you tick.
      </div>
    </div>';
$textarea = preg_replace('(<div class="dotted-highlight">){1,}(.*?)', '', $textarea);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve it with PHP DOM and XPath:

```
    $html = "<<HTML STRING>>";
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML("<div id=\"tmptmptmp\">" . $html . "</div>", LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    $xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $links = $xp->query('//div');
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        $class = $link->getAttribute('class');
        $nested = $xp->query('.//div', $link);
        foreach ($nested as $n) {
            if ($n->getAttribute('class') == $class) {
               //$html = $doc->getElementsByTagName("html")->item(0);
               $fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
               while ($n->childNodes->length > 0) {
                 $fragment->appendChild($n->childNodes->item(0));
               }
              $n->parentNode->replaceChild($fragment, $n);
            }
         }
    }
    echo preg_replace('/^\s*<div\s+id="tmptmptmp">\s*|\s*<\/div>\s*$/', '', $dom->saveHTML());
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/5cB7SJ)

Note that the `preg_replace` is only used to post-process the manually added `<div>` that helps work around issues arising when the HTML code is not a proper HTML document (e.g. without `<html>` and `<body>` tags).

Comment: Working, did not even thought about dom was thinking on a 1 line code regex. But it's ok. Thank you.

Comment: When it comes to nested structures, I'd rather go with the right tool. Regex is powerful enough in PCRE, but this is HTML and I think it is safer to play according to its rules in such cases.

Comment: One issue it removes all the html from the inner div https://ideone.com/U1oL75. I have an ul that got removed, this doesn't need to get removed, need only the div with matching class to do that.

Comment: Please check [this update](https://ideone.com/J7arhR). Whitespace is a bit messy, but the children are preserved.

Comment: Another odd thing happens https://ideone.com/OOrU24. Added after the closed div (highlitte-ddotted) a h2 and a strong tag, but somehow it merged to the parent div And this was outside the parent div. you need to look at the $html varialbe to see the string, in the end of the string after </div>.

Comment: :) That is something I have not seen yet, but it is something we can expect because the HTML you pass is not a proper document, just a fragment. Here is [a workaround](https://ideone.com/5cB7SJ).

Comment: Seams to be working there debugging on my complexer script.